# FCM creating errors in JSON formatting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

A webservice is sending the following notification to me on Android via FCM:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "123456"
  ],
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "notification_type": "request_accepted",
    "feedback": "request accepted"
  }
}
```

However on Android, in `onMessageReceived`, it becomes this:

```
{
    google.sent_time=1525800030866, 
    notification_type=request_accepted,
    google.ttl=2419200,
    feedback=request accepted,
    from=875234321904, 
    google.message_id=0:1525800030873951%137ecd
}
```

The above is obviously invalid JSON. Why does it become so and how can this be fixed?

There is other data in the payload that comes through fine with proper JSON formatting (: instead of =). However these few parameters have the incorrect formatting.

**EDIT:** `onMessageReceived`:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            if(remoteMessage.getData() != null)
            {
                parseJson(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Object parseJson(String json)
    {
        Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
        JsonAdapter<ClientRequestAcceptedModel> responseAdapter = moshi.adapter(ClientRequestAcceptedModel.class);
        try
        {
            return responseAdapter.fromJson(json);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**More JSON objects**

```
{
    "notification_type": "request_accepted",
    "partner_information": "{\"zip\":\"24000\"}",
    "feedback": "request accepted",
    "request_information": "{\"request_type\":\"custom\",\"status\":0}"
}
```

The partner information and request information isn't appearing the way it should be.

Comment: Do post your `onMessageReceived()` code as well.

Comment: @AL. added the code.

Comment: Thanks. It looks fine. I think one thing you missed is that `remoteMessage.getData()` does return a `Map<S,S>` object, not a JSONObject. This is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Although I've run into another issue now. There are two other objects in my json. I've added them to the code and how they're appearing now.

Answer (score 0):

that is expected behaviour

when you call remoteMessage.getData(), you will be getting a map.

```
Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
```

to get json you need to add the following

```
JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(params);
Log.d("This is the json", jobject());
```

so your codes should be something like

```
Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();

if(params != null)
{
    JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(params);
    parseJson(jobject.toString());
}
```

Comment: If there is other nested data in the json, will this correctly parse that as json too?

Comment: for firebase cloud messaging, data is always stored as key value. refer to https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging